# How can I Scrape next pages with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Here is my scrapy code.I dont know my mistake but in only scrapes first page.How can i scrape and traverse through pages ? Is there any other way for scraping next pages ?

```
import scrapy

class HurriyetEmlakPage(scrapy.Spider):
    
    name = 'hurriyetspider'
    allowed_domain = 'hurriyetemlak.com'
    start_urls = ['https://www.hurriyetemlak.com/satilik']
    
    def parse(self, response):
       
       fiyat = response.xpath('//div[@class="list-view-price"]//text()').extract()
       durum = response.xpath('//div[@class="middle sibling"]//div[@class="left"]//text()').extract()
       oda_sayisi = response.xpath('//span[@class="celly houseRoomCount"]//text()').extract()
       metrekare = response.xpath('//span[@class="celly squareMeter list-view-size"]//text()').extract()
       bina_yasi = response.xpath('//span[@class="celly buildingAge"]//text()').extract()
       bulundugu_kat = response.xpath('//span[@class="celly floortype"]//text()').extract()
       konum = response.xpath('//div[@class="list-view-location"]//text()').extract()

       scraped_info = {
            'fiyat':fiyat,
            'durum': durum,
            'oda_sayisi' : oda_sayisi,
            'metrekare' : metrekare,
            'bina_yasi' : bina_yasi,
            'bulundugu_kat': bulundugu_kat,
            'konum' : konum
        }
       yield scraped_info
       next_page_url = response.xpath('//li[@class="next-li pagi-nav"]//a').extract_first()
       if next_page_url:
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url = next_page_url,callback = self.parse)
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you could simply generate your url list like this :

```
url_list = [f"https://www.hurriyetemlak.com/satilik?page={page}" for page in range(1,7326)]
```

Output

```
['https://www.hurriyetemlak.com/satilik?page=1',
 'https://www.hurriyetemlak.com/satilik?page=2',
 'https://www.hurriyetemlak.com/satilik?page=3',
 'https://www.hurriyetemlak.com/satilik?page=4',
 'https://www.hurriyetemlak.com/satilik?page=5',
  ...]
```

Comment: this worked fine but it saves results of 1 page in 1 row on .csv file any solution for that ?

Comment: not sure I understand the issue. You mean that only on page 1 you're facing this? You may try to change page 1's url to https://www.hurriyetemlak.com/satilik

Comment: 1 row in csv output saves information of 24 ads(1 page).Do you have any idea how can i solve that ? I